# JavasScript - jtable not display by recalling in click event

Tags: javascript, jquery-jtable

I am a newbee in JavaScript. I have a problem  when using jtable. Please help!

Here is my case: I create a table using jtable

```
 $(document).ready(function (){

 $("#roomlist").click(function(){  
    $("#content").empty().append(
    '<div class="filtering">find: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><button type="submit" id="LoadRecordsButton">search</button></div>'
    ).jtable({  
        title: 'roomlist',  
        paging: true,  
        pageSize: 2,  
        sorting: true,  
        defaultSorting: 'name ASC',  
        actions:{  
            listAction: base_url+'index.php/role/leader/listroom'  
        },  
        ajaxSettings: {  
          type: 'POST',  
          dataType: 'json'    
        },fields:{  
            uuid:{  
              key:true,    
              list:false  
            },  
            city:{  
              list:false    
            },    
....
```

autoload table when pageload :
    `$('#roomlist').click`

But when I try to load table using another link, my table not display:

```
$('#another_link').click(function(){    
    $('#roomlist').click();
});
```

Comment: well... $('#roomlist').click references the function of the jquery object.. but not invoking it.. 
try $('#roomlist').click();

Comment: tried $('#roomlist').click(); but problem still happen

Comment: Well... maybe a jsFiddle or show more portions of your code..
If the first invoke of the handler works, the handler function is probably ok. But you are not showing the other portions of the code that may be wrong. Plus.. you only showed half of the handler function to begin with...

Comment: Now I can solve the problem by adding a .jtable('destroy') before loading the table. Thanks a lot!